# Collection Sorting not working on Backbone.Marionette using restful Services

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, restful-url

I am building a collection on Backbone.Marionette heavily basing myself on the example provided by David Sulc on his book 'A Gentle Introduction to Backbone.Marionette' available here https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/commit/175fc9b7bddfa6fea86954eb769c0cfb3e163c1e.

for the moment i am still doing everything inline:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Marionette Contact Manager</title>
    <link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./css/application.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./css/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <span class="brand">Secret Identities</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="main-region" class="container">
    //main area
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="contact-list-item">
    <td> <%= lastName %></td><td> <%= firstName %> </td><td> <%= occupation %> </td>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="contact-list">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Occupation</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</script>

<script src="./js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./js/vendor/json2.js"></script>
<script src="./js/vendor/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="./js/vendor/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="./js/vendor/backbone.marionette.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var Application = new Marionette.Application();

    Application.addRegions({
        mainRegion: "#main-region"
    });

    Application.Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: "/rest/example/listHeroes"

    });

    Application.ContactCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Application.Contact,
        url: "/rest/example/listHeroes",
        comparator: "firstName"
    });

    Application.ContactItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: "tr",
        template: "#contact-list-item"
    });

    Application.ContactsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        tagName: "table",
        className: "table table-hover",
        template: "#contact-list",
        itemView: Application.ContactItemView,
        itemViewContainer: "tbody"
    });


    Application.on("initialize:after", function () {
        var list = new Application.ContactCollection;
        list.fetch();
        var contactsView = new Application.ContactsView({
            collection: list
        });


        Application.mainRegion.show(contactsView);
    });

    Application.start();
</script>
</body>
</html>


</body>
</html>
```

the Json Array returned by the rest get is

```
[{"firstName":"Bruce","lastName":"Wayne","occupation":"Industrialist"},{"firstName":"Steve","lastName":"Rogers","occupation":"Soldier"},{"firstName":"Natasha","lastName":"Romanov","occupation":"spy"},{"firstName":"Clark","lastName":"Kent","occupation":"Reporter"},{"firstName":"Hal","lastName":"Jordan","occupation":"Pilot"}]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it is working perfectly fine.. You have the  `comparator: "firstName"`  .. But the labels are swapped in the View when rendered. So you might just have been confused.. Template `<td> <%= lastName %></td><td> <%= firstName %> `  Header `<tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>`  Fixed fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/HxtDs/

Comment: I realized that the labels where switched, but that's only the header, there is no actual change in the list, based on either field.I even checked by only leaving one field on it.

Comment: Works fine in the fiddle that I posted

Comment: Looks sorted right http://imgur.com/WPMtbpB

Comment: it only sorts it if the data is coming from a JSON array, not from a restful function

Comment: @Sushanth - I edited your fiddle to simulate fetch - http://jsfiddle.net/HxtDs/1/ ... Now to fix the issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. <del>Looks like a Backbone bug.</del>
When you add the items to the collection it calls Collection.set which first puts all the fetched elements in an array called toAdd. Then it adds from the toAdd collection to the internal models collection but then it triggers the events on the toAdd collection! Therefore the "add" events are triggered in the same order as you received them from the server.
https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L733

Marionette hooks to the "add" event so it can render the elements and therefore they are rendered in the same order of the toAdd collection which is the order you receive from the server.

So to fix the issue you can pass {reset: true} in the options of the fetch call:
http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

Thanks,
Boris

Edit: I don't think this is a Backbone bug, I think this is intentional for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if only writing the model field name as comparator would help. Instead you can write a custom function in comparator something like below:

```
comparator : function (m1, m2) {
    var str1, str2;

    str1 = m1.get('firstName');
    str2 = m2.get('firstName');

    if (str1 && str2) {
        str1 = str1.toLowerCase();
        str2 = str2.toLowerCase();

       if (str1 > str2) {
            return 1;
        } else if(str2 > str1) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

This would sort your collection every time you add/remove a model to the collection or call the collections `sort` method

Comment: if i change to a static list, like             var list = new Application.ContactCollection( [{lastName:'Batman'},{lastName:"Captain 'Merica"},{lastName:'Black Widow'},{lastName:'Superman'},{lastName:'Green Lantern'}]); it works fine. This was after I added a default field for the model and changed the comparator to lastName.

Comment: I tried something like that, as per the book, and the result is still no sorting =/

Comment: can u do a `list.sort()` below `list.fetch();`, along with the logic I have mentioned..

Comment: I have tried this, and while it works if i pass in a JSON array directly, it does not sort from restful service